# How to send data from ReactJs to signalR? In Asp.net Mvc Web Api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, react-native, signalr

Im getting a problem when i want to send data from React Component to hub It's Not send...
Note Hub is connected to client But Data Not Send/Recieve

Hub Code

```
public void SendMessageToAll(string userName, string message)
        {
             Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message );

        }
```

React Js Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hubConnection } from 'signalr-no-jquery';


class Dashboard extends Component {
   constructor(props) {    
   super(props);
   const connection = hubConnection('https://localhost:44332');
   const hubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('Chat');

   hubProxy.on('Hello', function(name) {
    console.log(name);
});
    // atempt connection, and handle errors
    connection.start()

    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
}


  render() {
    return (
        <div/>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Well you are not invoking any function to send the message. Why dont you look at this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio also  use the official microsoft package with react https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Comment: So how to create function  that send a message? please help for this code I am new in reactjs...

Comment: Check the link.

Comment: Thank you @sujit Warrier

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when using SignalR, we will create the ChatHub.cs, which contains the send/receive method. In the client side, we will declare a proxy to reference the hub and connect the hub, then, we can call the hub's send/receive method to transfer the message. But from your code, I didn't find where you call the "SendMessageToAll()" method, so the message will not send. Please check your code.

Here are some tutorials about using SignalR, you can check them:

[Chat Application Using ASP.NET, ReactJS, Web API, SignalR and Gulp](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1082191/Chat-Application-Using-ASP-NET-ReactJS-Web-API-Sig)

[Tutorial: Real-time chat with SignalR 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)